# Timeline input fields, how to display?

Tags: timeline

in this my project I see for first time input fields in the left of the timeline; I don't know how I did it..
in other projects I don't know how to show/hide these very useful fields!!
[image: timeline with input fields]

Answer (score 4):

You need to enable *View > Show Sliders*:

[image]

Comment: Nice. I'm wondering why this isn't available in the Timeline > View menu ? Another ui papercut I guess...

Comment: They talked about merging Dope Sheet and Timeline, I don't know why they gave up, it would make more sense in my opinion, they share a lot of functions... but I may miss something...

Comment: thank you very much, moonboots!

Answer (score 2):

For other peoples.. now I realized that this option is not available in timeline, I've to switch to dope sheet to activate slider, after that I can see also in timeline..